# How to test sorting of a json-api in a leagacy system

Tags: php, sorting, phpunit, lumen, json-api

I'm creating a REST-API with the json-API specification for a leagacy project with lumen. How to unit test the sorting accodingly? The database could not be seeded without a huge rewrite. So I tried to fetch the data and sort it via array_multisort to produce the expected result. The response form the API is sorted via ORDER BY form the database.

How to check the sorting mechanism? The HTTP status codes are already checke correct.

Comment: the only possible answer to this question is 'by sorting' unless you show some json, some code, and possibly some sql, as well state the intended result and how the obtained result differs.

Comment: I currently have no code (I'm not at work). I don't remember which one is the expected an what is the wrong one but important is the difference:
1. "Al Foo", "Al@Bar" "Albar",
2. "Albar", "Al Foo" "Al@Bar"
How to modify the sorting  in php to match the sorting in postgre in the test unit

Comment: Are you using a library to write your JSON:API? [Laravel JSON API](https://laravel-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has an awesome testing integration.

Comment: If the database can not be seeded with testing data in a testing environment something fishy is going on. I would address that problem first. Testing based on production data which might even change is not stable, raises the complexity and may introduce security issues. Are you importing the existing data in your testing environment? Or are you even running your tests against production database?